# Error when using GridSearchCV and RandomizedSearchCV

Tags: python-3.x, scipy, scikit-learn, sparse-matrix, cross-validation

When attempting to fit my training data using either [`GridSearchCV`](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.GridSearchCV.html) or [`RandomizedSearchCV`](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.RandomizedSearchCV.html), I keep getting the following error:

> TypeError: no supported conversion for types: (dtype('O'), dtype('O'))

Here's a sample of the relevant code:

```
from xgboost.sklearn import XGBRegressor as XGR
from sklearn.model_selection import RandomizedSearchCV, GridSearchCV

xgbRegModel = XGR()
params = {'max_depth':[3, 6, 9], 'learning_rate':[.05, .1, .5], 'n_estimators': [50, 100, 200]}

rscv = RandomizedSearchCV(xgbRegModel, params)  
rscv.fit(X, y)  
rscv.best_model_
```

where `X` is a (39942, 112577) [`scipy.sparse.csr.csr_matrix`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.sparse.csr_matrix.html) and `y` is a (39942,) [`numpy.ndarray`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.html).

The dtypes are all either `int64` or `float64`, and I've tried running it both with `np.nan` values and after filling the `np.nan` values with 0... (I thought that might be the problem, but no.)

Can anyone tell me what's going on here? It works just fine when I train the model without using GridSearchCV or RandomizedSearchCV.

Any ideas would be appreciated - thanks!

ps - the traceback for the error is really long, but here it is, if it helps..

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-54-63d54d4cd03e> in <module>()
      3 xgbRegModel = XGR()
      4 rscv = RandomizedSearchCV(xgbRegModel, params)
----> 5 rscv.fit(X, y)
      6 rscv.best_model_

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\model_selection\_search.py in fit(self, X, y, groups, **fit_params)
    636                                   error_score=self.error_score)
    637           for parameters, (train, test) in product(candidate_params,
--> 638                                                    cv.split(X, y, groups)))
    639 
    640         # if one choose to see train score, "out" will contain train  score info

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\externals\joblib\parallel.py in __call__(self, iterable)
    777             # was dispatched. In particular this covers the edge
    778             # case of Parallel used with an exhausted iterator.
--> 779             while self.dispatch_one_batch(iterator):
    780                 self._iterating = True
    781             else:

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\externals\joblib\parallel.py in dispatch_one_batch(self, iterator)
    623                 return False
    624             else:
--> 625                 self._dispatch(tasks)
    626                 return True
    627 

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\externals\joblib\parallel.py in _dispatch(self, batch)
    586         dispatch_timestamp = time.time()
    587         cb = BatchCompletionCallBack(dispatch_timestamp, len(batch), self)
--> 588         job = self._backend.apply_async(batch, callback=cb)
    589         self._jobs.append(job)
    590 

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\externals\joblib\_parallel_backends.py in apply_async(self, func, callback)
    109     def apply_async(self, func, callback=None):
    110         """Schedule a func to be run"""
--> 111         result = ImmediateResult(func)
    112         if callback:
    113             callback(result)

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\externals\joblib\_parallel_backends.py in __init__(self, batch)
    330         # Don't delay the application, to avoid keeping the input
    331         # arguments in memory
--> 332         self.results = batch()
    333 
    334     def get(self):

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\externals\joblib\parallel.py in __call__(self)
    129 
    130     def __call__(self):
--> 131         return [func(*args, **kwargs) for func, args, kwargs in self.items]
    132 
    133     def __len__(self):

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\externals\joblib\parallel.py in     <listcomp>(.0)
    129 
    130     def __call__(self):
--> 131         return [func(*args, **kwargs) for func, args, kwargs in self.items]
    132 
    133     def __len__(self):

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\model_selection\_validation.py in _fit_and_score(estimator, X, y, scorer, train, test, verbose, parameters, fit_params, return_train_score, return_parameters, return_n_test_samples, return_times, error_score)
    425     start_time = time.time()
    426 
--> 427     X_train, y_train = _safe_split(estimator, X, y, train)
    428     X_test, y_test = _safe_split(estimator, X, y, test, train)
    429 

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\utils\metaestimators.py in _safe_split(estimator, X, y, indices, train_indices)
    198             X_subset = X[np.ix_(indices, train_indices)]
    199     else:
--> 200         X_subset = safe_indexing(X, indices)
    201 
    202     if y is not None:

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\utils\__init__.py in safe_indexing(X, indices)
    160             return X.take(indices, axis=0)
    161         else:
--> 162             return X[indices]
    163     else:
    164         return [X[idx] for idx in indices]

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\scipy\sparse\csr.py in __getitem__(self, key)
    315             if isintlike(col) or isinstance(col,slice):
    316                 P = extractor(row, self.shape[0])     # [[1,2],j] or [[1,2],1:2]
--> 317                 extracted = P * self
    318                 if col == slice(None, None, None):
    319                     return extracted

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\scipy\sparse\base.py in __mul__(self, other)
    367             if self.shape[1] != other.shape[0]:
    368                 raise ValueError('dimension mismatch')
--> 369             return self._mul_sparse_matrix(other)
    370 
    371         # If it's a list or whatever, treat it like a matrix

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\scipy\sparse\compressed.py in _mul_sparse_matrix(self, other)
    539         indptr = np.asarray(indptr, dtype=idx_dtype)
    540         indices = np.empty(nnz, dtype=idx_dtype)
--> 541         data = np.empty(nnz, dtype=upcast(self.dtype, other.dtype))
    542 
    543         fn = getattr(_sparsetools, self.format + '_matmat_pass2')

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\scipy\sparse\sputils.py in upcast(*args)
     49             return t
     50 
---> 51     raise TypeError('no supported conversion for types: %r' % (args,))
     52 
     53 

TypeError: no supported conversion for types: (dtype('O'), dtype('O'))
```

Answer (score 1):

Thats because GridSearchCV doesn't support sparse matrices in the fit() method. Please have a look at the signature of [fit method here](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.GridSearchCV.html#sklearn.model_selection.GridSearchCV.fit):

Parameters:

```
X : array-like, shape = [n_samples, n_features]
```

As you see its written that only array-like inputs are supported.

As for why its working normally without grid search, thats because XGBRegressor supports sparse matrices.

The actual error arises when during cross_validation, the X is splitted into train and test which doesn't work for sparse matrices same way as normal arrays.

Also, make sure that for XGBRegressor the sparse matrix is of type `CSC` and not `CSR` as you have now, because it will give you wrong results. Its described here: https://github.com/dmlc/xgboost/issues/1238

Comment: can I conclude that I can not use gridsearch for the multi label data as the data passed to the estimator needs to be sparse matric?

Comment: The same question from me